# How to use "question mark" in start method of UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, testbench, verification, uvm

I am trying to modify the existing code using the `start()` method in UVM.

Basic code is below:

```
function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
 uvm_config_wrapper::set(this, "tb.chan?.rx_agent.sequencer.run_phase",
 "default_sequence",
 channel_rx_resp_seq::get_type()); 
endfunction
```

I implemented the code below instead of the original code, but "`?`" is giving an illegal expression primary error.

How do I correctly implement "`?`" in `start()` method of UVM?

```
ch_seq.start("tb.chan?.rx_agent.sequencer");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a list of sequencers using `uvm_top.find_all()` and then loop through all the sequencers starting them in parallel.

```
uvm_component comps[$];
uvm_sequencer_base sqrs[$];

uvm_top.find_all("tb.chan?.rx_agent.sequencer",comps);
foreach(comps[i]) begin // need to downcast each sequencer handle to pass to start argument
     sqrs.push_back(null);
     $cast(sqrs[i],comps[i])
end
foreach(sqrs[i]) fork
    int j = i;
    begin
      // create a new sequence for each sequencer
      channel_rx_resp_seq ch_seq = channel_rx_resp_seq::type_id::create();
      ch_seq.start(sqrs[j]);
    end
  join_none
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the `start` method of a `uvm_sequence` should be of type `uvm_sequencer_base`.

However, you passed it an argument of type `string`.  The double quotes create a `string`.

I don't think you can pass a string to `start` like `"tb.chan?.rx_agent.sequencer"`.  Typically, you would pass a handle to a `uvm_sequencer` object.

Refer to the "Sequences" section of the [UVM documentation](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/index.html).

Also, if you are trying to use `?` as some sort of regular expression match character, so that it would match *multiple* things like `chan0`, `chan1`, etc., I think you can only pass a *single* instance of a sequencer to `start`.

If you want to start the sequence on a sequencer under the `chan0` hierarchy:

```
ch_seq.start(tb.chan0.rx_agent.sequencer);
```